# In sandbox I am seeing only 3 types of event types in EventLogFile Object

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring, log-analysis

As I am querying records From EventLogFile object only 3 types of events are retrived i.e. API Total uses, Login and Logout Event. records are generating but only for this 3 types of events. why i am facing this issue as my profile is of system admin and all the permission is given as it is.
why records are not generating for any other type of events?

Comment: Swetha's answer is correct.

Comment: Please tell me the license name.

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/shield/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the trailhead [doc](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro)

> The event types you can access and how long the files remain available depends on your Salesforce edition.
>
> - Developer Edition organizations have free access to all log types with 1-day data retention.
> - Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Edition organizations have free access to the insecure external assets, login, logout, and total API usage event log files with 1-day data retention. For an extra cost, you can access all log file types with 30-day data retention.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339868&type=1) you need to

> Contact your Salesforce sales representative or Account Executive to purchase the Event Monitoring add-on to access all event types